# JQuery UI: draggable element is transparent. How to make it not?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using JQuery UI 1.10.3 to build a list of draggable elements.

When I drag an element over another element, I notice that the white area of the dragged element is transparent and I am able to see the element beneath.

How to make it not transparent?

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/UW5E2/4/

```
<ul>
  <li id="draggable">Drag me down</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>

 $(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: true
    });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#sortable",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  });

  ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }
  li { margin: 5px; padding: 15px; width: 150px; border: 1px solid #000}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Updated as you requested. When you move one item onto another item, you can see the item beneath. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just give the draggable element a bigger `z-index` value (CSS) with `position` attribute as '`relative`'.

```
z-index: 9999;
position: relative;
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Rajesh, thanks soooooooooooooooooooooo much for helping me. I tried it. I created a CSS class, which is attached to the dragged object when it is being dragged. I even made the dragged object have a color border in the CSS class when being dragged, and I did see that border color. But I still see through the dragged object. However, if I give the dragged object a background (which I dont want), the dragged object is completely opaque.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by simply attaching a CSS class to the draggable and this CSS class indicates its background-color is #fefefe (kind of white). The problem I have is that the white space area of the draggale is transparent.

I dont feel what I did is a right solution, but it works so far. Still love to see any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a background color for the dragging element. Without it, the dragging element has no background color therefore it looks 'transparent' or with an opacity of zero. Set the background color on the dragging element style.